# How to interpolate and visualize a finite element integration point solution

Tags: finite-element-method, visualization, solidmechanics, postprocessing

I can intepolate the **nodal** solution using the function `ufun = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, nodalsol]` and visualize the **nodal** solution with the function `SliceContourPlot3D[ufun[x, y, z], MeshRegion[mesh], Element[{x, y, z}, mesh]]`.
But so far I haven't found a way to interpolate the solution based on the values ​​at the **integration points**.

Here is the mesh were I want to plot the solution:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
re = 200;
ri = 100;
H = 20;
nx = 10; ny = 3; nz = 3;
\[Theta]1 = 0;
\[Theta]2 = Pi/2;
coordinates = 
  Flatten[Table[{r Cos[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]], h}, {h, 0, H, 
     H/(nz - 1)}, {r, ri, re, (re - ri)/(ny - 1)}, {\[Theta], 
     0., \[Theta]2, \[Theta]2/(nx - 1)}], 2];
incidents = 
  Flatten[Table[
    Block[{p1 = (j - 1)*nx + i, p2 = j*nx + i, p3 = p2 + 1, 
      p4 = p1 + 1, p5, p6, p7, 
      p8}, {p5, p6, p7, p8} = {p1, p2, p3, p4} + k*nx*ny;
     {p1, p2, p3, p4} += (k - 1)*nx*ny;
     {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8}], {i, 1, nx - 1}, {j, 1, 
     ny - 1}, {k, 1, nz - 1}], 2];
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, 
  "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[incidents]}, 
  "NodeReordering" -> True]
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], 
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
   "MeshElementIDStyle" -> Red]]]
```

[image]

and here is the integration points solutions that I want to visualize:
(the data format is  {{x,y,z,val},...,{xn,yn,zn,valn}})

```
data={{110.211, 4.05736, 2.11325, -27.1079}, {110.211, 4.05736, 
  7.88675, -28.2094}, {109.241, 15.1423, 2.11325, 157.554}, {109.241, 
  15.1423, 7.88675, 159.371}, {138.986, 5.11669, 2.11325, 
  18.4429}, {138.986, 5.11669, 7.88675, 16.9932}, {137.763, 19.0957, 
  2.11325, -13.2305}, {137.763, 19.0957, 7.88675, -12.6677}, {110.211,
   4.05736, 12.1132, -28.2094}, {110.211, 4.05736, 
  17.8868, -26.4777}, {109.241, 15.1423, 12.1132, 159.338}, {109.241, 
  15.1423, 17.8868, 157.451}, {138.986, 5.11669, 12.1132, 
  16.9399}, {138.986, 5.11669, 17.8868, 18.1711}, {137.763, 19.0957, 
  12.1132, -12.6677}, {137.763, 19.0957, 17.8868, -13.2305}, {160.051,
   5.89217, 2.11325, 52.1731}, {160.051, 5.89217, 7.88675, 
  50.2772}, {158.642, 21.9899, 2.11325, 15.3157}, {158.642, 21.9899, 
  7.88675, 18.3606}, {188.826, 6.95149, 2.11325, -0.425314}, {188.826,
   6.95149, 7.88675, -1.29793}, {187.164, 25.9433, 2.11325, 
  35.9674}, {187.164, 25.9433, 7.88675, 40.753}, {160.051, 5.89217, 
  12.1132, 50.3082}, {160.051, 5.89217, 17.8868, 52.3091}, {158.642, 
  21.9899, 12.1132, 18.3683}, {158.642, 21.9899, 17.8868, 
  15.3478}, {188.826, 6.95149, 12.1132, -1.29793}, {188.826, 6.95149, 
  17.8868, -0.411109}, {187.164, 25.9433, 12.1132, 40.742}, {187.164, 
  25.9433, 17.8868, 35.9237}, {107.832, 23.1337, 2.11325, 
  296.305}, {107.832, 23.1337, 7.88675, 294.663}, {104.952, 33.8818, 
  2.11325, 430.532}, {104.952, 33.8818, 7.88675, 423.043}, {135.986, 
  29.1736, 2.11325, -1.42184}, {135.986, 29.1736, 
  7.88675, -2.51491}, {132.354, 42.7279, 2.11325, 39.6828}, {132.354, 
  42.7279, 7.88675, 38.8425}, {107.832, 23.1337, 12.1132, 
  294.579}, {107.832, 23.1337, 17.8868, 296.023}, {104.952, 33.8818, 
  12.1132, 423.03}, {104.952, 33.8818, 17.8868, 430.448}, {135.986, 
  29.1736, 12.1132, -2.50587}, {135.986, 29.1736, 
  17.8868, -1.37515}, {132.354, 42.7279, 12.1132, 38.8506}, {132.354, 
  42.7279, 17.8868, 39.7108}, {156.596, 33.5952, 
  2.11325, -5.15224}, {156.596, 33.5952, 7.88675, -5.46623}, {152.414,
   49.2038, 2.11325, -3.55398}, {152.414, 49.2038, 
  7.88675, -3.41021}, {184.75, 39.6351, 2.11325, 24.9539}, {184.75, 
  39.6351, 7.88675, 24.1168}, {179.816, 58.0499, 2.11325, 
  2.58314}, {179.816, 58.0499, 7.88675, 2.20344}, {156.596, 33.5952, 
  12.1132, -5.46623}, {156.596, 33.5952, 17.8868, -5.15224}, {152.414,
   49.2038, 12.1132, -3.41021}, {152.414, 49.2038, 
  17.8868, -3.55398}, {184.75, 39.6351, 12.1132, 24.1312}, {184.75, 
  39.6351, 17.8868, 24.9992}, {179.816, 58.0499, 12.1132, 
  2.20649}, {179.816, 58.0499, 17.8868, 2.59417}, {102.177, 41.5071, 
  2.11325, 481.441}, {102.177, 41.5071, 7.88675, 473.081}, {97.4744, 
  51.5919, 2.11325, 447.534}, {97.4744, 51.5919, 7.88675, 
  439.029}, {128.854, 52.3442, 2.11325, 96.6757}, {128.854, 52.3442, 
  7.88675, 93.8762}, {122.924, 65.0619, 2.11325, 139.704}, {122.924, 
  65.0619, 7.88675, 136.859}, {102.177, 41.5071, 12.1132, 
  473.079}, {102.177, 41.5071, 17.8868, 481.416}, {97.4744, 51.5919, 
  12.1132, 439.031}, {97.4744, 51.5919, 17.8868, 447.569}, {128.854, 
  52.3442, 12.1132, 93.8772}, {128.854, 52.3442, 17.8868, 
  96.6675}, {122.924, 65.0619, 12.1132, 136.855}, {122.924, 65.0619, 
  17.8868, 139.687}, {148.383, 60.2774, 2.11325, 4.98339}, {148.383, 
  60.2774, 7.88675, 3.82956}, {141.554, 74.9226, 2.11325, 
  44.7941}, {141.554, 74.9226, 7.88675, 44.7128}, {175.06, 71.1144, 
  2.11325, 2.89622}, {175.06, 71.1144, 7.88675, 2.60949}, {167.003, 
  88.3926, 2.11325, 13.4524}, {167.003, 88.3926, 7.88675, 
  13.5723}, {148.383, 60.2774, 12.1132, 3.82996}, {148.383, 60.2774, 
  17.8868, 4.99664}, {141.554, 74.9226, 12.1132, 44.7155}, {141.554, 
  74.9226, 17.8868, 44.8019}, {175.06, 71.1144, 12.1132, 
  2.60949}, {175.06, 71.1144, 17.8868, 2.89726}, {167.003, 88.3926, 
  12.1132, 13.5747}, {167.003, 88.3926, 17.8868, 13.4615}, {93.4171, 
  58.6194, 2.11325, 373.599}, {93.4171, 58.6194, 7.88675, 
  367.519}, {87.0348, 67.7343, 2.11325, 224.59}, {87.0348, 67.7343, 
  7.88675, 222.024}, {117.807, 73.9242, 2.11325, 138.792}, {117.807, 
  73.9242, 7.88675, 134.538}, {109.758, 85.4189, 2.11325, 
  86.7638}, {109.758, 85.4189, 7.88675, 82.3625}, {93.4171, 58.6194, 
  12.1132, 367.526}, {93.4171, 58.6194, 17.8868, 373.626}, {87.0348, 
  67.7343, 12.1132, 222.025}, {87.0348, 67.7343, 17.8868, 
  224.589}, {117.807, 73.9242, 12.1132, 134.536}, {117.807, 73.9242, 
  17.8868, 138.789}, {109.758, 85.4189, 12.1132, 82.3631}, {109.758, 
  85.4189, 17.8868, 86.767}, {135.662, 85.1281, 2.11325, 
  61.3272}, {135.662, 85.1281, 7.88675, 60.781}, {126.393, 98.365, 
  2.11325, 28.4231}, {126.393, 98.365, 7.88675, 26.6579}, {160.052, 
  100.433, 2.11325, 20.2365}, {160.052, 100.433, 7.88675, 
  20.6496}, {149.117, 116.05, 2.11325, 0.597216}, {149.117, 116.05, 
  7.88675, 0.640594}, {135.662, 85.1281, 12.1132, 60.7827}, {135.662, 
  85.1281, 17.8868, 61.3335}, {126.393, 98.365, 12.1132, 
  26.6625}, {126.393, 98.365, 17.8868, 28.4418}, {160.052, 100.433, 
  12.1132, 20.6524}, {160.052, 100.433, 17.8868, 20.2455}, {149.117, 
  116.05, 12.1132, 0.642497}, {149.117, 116.05, 17.8868, 
  0.60428}, {81.8187, 73.9506, 2.11325, 117.608}, {81.8187, 73.9506, 
  7.88675, 115.448}, {73.9506, 81.8187, 2.11325, -40.1007}, {73.9506, 
  81.8187, 7.88675, -40.8911}, {103.181, 93.2582, 2.11325, 
  6.13177}, {103.181, 93.2582, 7.88675, 2.70952}, {93.2582, 103.181, 
  2.11325, -108.048}, {93.2582, 103.181, 7.88675, -110.175}, {81.8187,
   73.9506, 12.1132, 115.447}, {81.8187, 73.9506, 17.8868, 
  117.603}, {73.9506, 81.8187, 12.1132, -40.8903}, {73.9506, 81.8187, 
  17.8868, -40.0999}, {103.181, 93.2582, 12.1132, 2.71098}, {103.181, 
  93.2582, 17.8868, 6.13691}, {93.2582, 103.181, 
  12.1132, -110.169}, {93.2582, 103.181, 17.8868, -108.028}, {118.819,
   107.392, 2.11325, -25.0602}, {118.819, 107.392, 
  7.88675, -27.6502}, {107.392, 118.819, 2.11325, -120.177}, {107.392,
   118.819, 7.88675, -122.811}, {140.18, 126.7, 
  2.11325, -29.035}, {140.18, 126.7, 7.88675, -30.1814}, {126.7, 
  140.18, 2.11325, -60.0967}, {126.7, 140.18, 
  7.88675, -61.3642}, {118.819, 107.392, 12.1132, -27.6436}, {118.819,
   107.392, 17.8868, -25.0363}, {107.392, 118.819, 
  12.1132, -122.803}, {107.392, 118.819, 17.8868, -120.149}, {140.18, 
  126.7, 12.1132, -30.1788}, {140.18, 126.7, 
  17.8868, -29.0244}, {126.7, 140.18, 12.1132, -61.3576}, {126.7, 
  140.18, 17.8868, -60.0721}, {67.7343, 87.0348, 
  2.11325, -151.303}, {67.7343, 87.0348, 7.88675, -152.103}, {58.6194,
   93.4171, 2.11325, -314.67}, {58.6194, 93.4171, 
  7.88675, -313.121}, {85.4189, 109.758, 2.11325, -189.312}, {85.4189,
   109.758, 7.88675, -189.631}, {73.9242, 117.807, 
  2.11325, -224.515}, {73.9242, 117.807, 7.88675, -222.709}, {67.7343,
   87.0348, 12.1132, -152.101}, {67.7343, 87.0348, 
  17.8868, -151.293}, {58.6194, 93.4171, 12.1132, -313.109}, {58.6194,
   93.4171, 17.8868, -314.632}, {85.4189, 109.758, 
  12.1132, -189.624}, {85.4189, 109.758, 17.8868, -189.287}, {73.9242,
   117.807, 12.1132, -222.697}, {73.9242, 117.807, 
  17.8868, -224.474}, {98.365, 126.393, 2.11325, -147.67}, {98.365, 
  126.393, 7.88675, -149.853}, {85.1281, 135.662, 
  2.11325, -132.585}, {85.1281, 135.662, 7.88675, -133.617}, {116.05, 
  149.117, 2.11325, -62.4022}, {116.05, 149.117, 
  7.88675, -64.2014}, {100.433, 160.052, 2.11325, -37.3254}, {100.433,
   160.052, 7.88675, -37.5645}, {98.365, 126.393, 
  12.1132, -149.846}, {98.365, 126.393, 17.8868, -147.642}, {85.1281, 
  135.662, 12.1132, -133.606}, {85.1281, 135.662, 
  17.8868, -132.543}, {116.05, 149.117, 12.1132, -64.1941}, {116.05, 
  149.117, 17.8868, -62.374}, {100.433, 160.052, 
  12.1132, -37.5532}, {100.433, 160.052, 17.8868, -37.2898}, {51.5919,
   97.4744, 2.11325, -403.033}, {51.5919, 97.4744, 
  7.88675, -398.552}, {41.5071, 102.177, 2.11325, -460.178}, {41.5071,
   102.177, 7.88675, -454.346}, {65.0619, 122.924, 
  2.11325, -204.727}, {65.0619, 122.924, 7.88675, -203.351}, {52.3442,
   128.854, 2.11325, -126.359}, {52.3442, 128.854, 
  7.88675, -123.107}, {51.5919, 97.4744, 12.1132, -398.557}, {51.5919,
   97.4744, 17.8868, -403.02}, {41.5071, 102.177, 
  12.1132, -454.32}, {41.5071, 102.177, 17.8868, -460.08}, {65.0619, 
  122.924, 12.1132, -203.34}, {65.0619, 122.924, 
  17.8868, -204.683}, {52.3442, 128.854, 12.1132, -123.1}, {52.3442, 
  128.854, 17.8868, -126.332}, {74.9226, 141.554, 
  2.11325, -71.7192}, {74.9226, 141.554, 7.88675, -71.2711}, {60.2774,
   148.383, 2.11325, 15.0762}, {60.2774, 148.383, 7.88675, 
  17.0593}, {88.3926, 167.003, 2.11325, 5.32159}, {88.3926, 167.003, 
  7.88675, 6.92199}, {71.1144, 175.06, 2.11325, 23.2051}, {71.1144, 
  175.06, 7.88675, 22.9277}, {74.9226, 141.554, 
  12.1132, -71.2606}, {74.9226, 141.554, 17.8868, -71.6793}, {60.2774,
   148.383, 12.1132, 17.0624}, {60.2774, 148.383, 17.8868, 
  15.0862}, {88.3926, 167.003, 12.1132, 6.93024}, {88.3926, 167.003, 
  17.8868, 5.35503}, {71.1144, 175.06, 12.1132, 22.9277}, {71.1144, 
  175.06, 17.8868, 23.2051}, {33.8818, 104.952, 
  2.11325, -423.286}, {33.8818, 104.952, 7.88675, -416.993}, {23.1337,
   107.832, 2.11325, -294.799}, {23.1337, 107.832, 
  7.88675, -295.688}, {42.7279, 132.354, 2.11325, -38.7388}, {42.7279,
   132.354, 7.88675, -37.1771}, {29.1736, 135.986, 2.11325, 
  22.7708}, {29.1736, 135.986, 7.88675, 23.0541}, {33.8818, 104.952, 
  12.1132, -416.97}, {33.8818, 104.952, 17.8868, -423.213}, {23.1337, 
  107.832, 12.1132, -295.657}, {23.1337, 107.832, 
  17.8868, -294.784}, {42.7279, 132.354, 12.1132, -37.1848}, {42.7279,
   132.354, 17.8868, -38.7729}, {29.1736, 135.986, 12.1132, 
  23.0265}, {29.1736, 135.986, 17.8868, 22.6398}, {49.2038, 152.414, 
  2.11325, 28.8077}, {49.2038, 152.414, 7.88675, 29.2139}, {33.5952, 
  156.596, 2.11325, 31.3561}, {33.5952, 156.596, 7.88675, 
  30.5477}, {58.0499, 179.816, 2.11325, 20.1825}, {58.0499, 179.816, 
  7.88675, 21.5106}, {39.6351, 184.75, 2.11325, -18.6052}, {39.6351, 
  184.75, 7.88675, -18.406}, {49.2038, 152.414, 12.1132, 
  29.2139}, {49.2038, 152.414, 17.8868, 28.8077}, {33.5952, 156.596, 
  12.1132, 30.5477}, {33.5952, 156.596, 17.8868, 31.3561}, {58.0499, 
  179.816, 12.1132, 21.5215}, {58.0499, 179.816, 17.8868, 
  20.218}, {39.6351, 184.75, 12.1132, -18.4377}, {39.6351, 184.75, 
  17.8868, -18.7311}, {15.1423, 109.241, 2.11325, -156.91}, {15.1423, 
  109.241, 7.88675, -158.531}, {4.05736, 110.211, 2.11325, 
  53.8805}, {4.05736, 110.211, 7.88675, 54.4221}, {19.0957, 137.763, 
  2.11325, 37.428}, {19.0957, 137.763, 7.88675, 38.8741}, {5.11669, 
  138.986, 2.11325, 9.89016}, {5.11669, 138.986, 7.88675, 
  10.598}, {15.1423, 109.241, 12.1132, -158.557}, {15.1423, 109.241, 
  17.8868, -157.001}, {4.05736, 110.211, 12.1132, 54.4221}, {4.05736, 
  110.211, 17.8868, 52.8032}, {19.0957, 137.763, 12.1132, 
  38.8741}, {19.0957, 137.763, 17.8868, 37.428}, {5.11669, 138.986, 
  12.1132, 10.5151}, {5.11669, 138.986, 17.8868, 9.73325}, {21.9899, 
  158.642, 2.11325, -2.9468}, {21.9899, 158.642, 
  7.88675, -5.7705}, {5.89217, 160.051, 2.11325, -42.9544}, {5.89217, 
  160.051, 7.88675, -42.0609}, {25.9433, 187.164, 
  2.11325, -47.1769}, {25.9433, 187.164, 7.88675, -55.4498}, {6.95149,
   188.826, 2.11325, 23.9922}, {6.95149, 188.826, 7.88675, 
  26.568}, {21.9899, 158.642, 12.1132, -5.76188}, {21.9899, 158.642, 
  17.8868, -2.92501}, {5.89217, 160.051, 12.1132, -42.1414}, {5.89217,
   160.051, 17.8868, -43.217}, {25.9433, 187.164, 
  12.1132, -55.4532}, {25.9433, 187.164, 17.8868, -47.1823}, {6.95149,
   188.826, 12.1132, 26.568}, {6.95149, 188.826, 17.8868, 23.9197}}
```

Can anyone help? The plot I expect is something like this:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the first place? I mean why not use assemble the integration points to a list of nodal points?

Comment: I'm solving elastoplastic problem, and in this kind of simulation the values of the plastic deformation are available only at the integration points.

Comment: What is `nodalsol`? Please post the equations of such elastoplastic problem.

Comment: In a finite element approximation of an elasticity problem, the solution (displacement) is given in the mesh nodes. `nodalsol` is a vector with the size o the mesh nodes with the displacement values. In my case I have the solution only at the integration points.

Comment: @Stratus I agree with cvgmt, it would be much simpler to give helpful answer if you provide your FEM solution (not only  "integrationpoints")

Comment: Do you want to convert the values at the integration point to values at the nodal point to then make an interpolating function? I mean what value should you solution have at, say, node, 1, seen that you want to visualize your values over the entire domain.

Answer (score 4):

You can create the interpolating function as:

```mathematica
datafun = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1 ];
evfun = EvaluateOnElementMesh[{x, y, z}, datafun[x, y, z], mesh];
```

And then plot it over the mesh faces with:

```mathematica
SliceContourPlot3D[evfun[x, y, z], mesh, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

You could plo `datafun` directly but this will give you a worse graphics result. To increase the quality of the contours you basically need more elements such to reduce the gap between the integration points and avoid artifact due to the interpolation (legend min/max different from `MinMax[data[[All,4]]]` ).

Comment: Welcome to SE! You could also add an extrapolation handler.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you look for `ListDensityPlot3D[...]`

Try

```
    {rmin, rmax} = MinMax[Map[Sqrt[# . #] &, coordinates]]
    Show[{ListDensityPlot3D[data, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, rmin < Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] < rmax] ], 
  Graphics3D[{Gray, Point[data[[All, {1, 2, 3}]]] }], 
  mesh["Wireframe"]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: In my mma version 11.3.0.0 this command return nothing.

Comment: @Stratus Strange, command was introduced with Mathematica v10.2 .

Comment: @Stratus Workaround: `Graphics3D[{ Map[{Hue[#[[-1]]], Point[Most[#]]} &, data ]} ]`